# Async Future, How to send an event back to caller that a single item has been fetched?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making a Future method that lives inside a seperate class, that fetches a bunch XKCD comics, and puts them in a List and returns it.

And that is all fine and dandy, but I would like to notify back when a single comic has been fetched, so I can show a progress dialog, on how far we are.

This is my code:

```
// This is inside my class ComicManager
Future<List<ComicModel>> generateComicList() async {
  List<ComicModel> comicList = new List<ComicModel>();

  ComicModel latestComic = await getLatestComic();

  for (var i = 1; i <= latestComic.num; i++) {
    try {
      http.Response response =
          await http.get('https://xkcd.com/${i}/info.0.json');

      Map comicmap = json.decode(response.body);
      var comic = new ComicModel.fromJson(comicmap);
      comicList.add(comic);
      print(comic.num);

      // Notify here that we have fetched a comic

    } catch (ex) {
      // Comic could apparently not be parsed, skip it.
    }
  }

  return comicList;
}
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

I just used `Streams` like so:

```
Stream<ComicProgressModel> getAllComicsStream() async* {
  // Do what you need to do here

  // This will respond back when you are listening to the stream
  yield stuffToYield; // Can be anything, and you can yield as many times you want

  // When you reach the end of the method, the onDone method will be called. 
  // So if you are running a for loop, and call yield multiple times it onDone is only called the the this method ends
}
```

Then I can just listen to events like so:

```
Stream comicStream =
      ComicManager().getAllComicsStream().asBroadcastStream();

StreamSubscription comicsub = comicStream.listen((onData) {
  // Do what i need
});
```

Super easy to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no particularly elegant way to do this. From some flutter code samples, it seems using `VoidCallBack` listeners is an accepted way.

First register callback functions in a `Set`

```
Set<VoidCallBack> listeners
```

Then define the callback functions you needed. And add them to the set

```
void fun()
//...
listeners.add(fun);//Or you can define a method to do this or simply pass the function through the constructor of this class.
```

Finally, write a `notifyListeners` function or its equivalent and call it wherever you want

```
void notifyListeners(){
    for(final listener in listeners){
        listener();
    }
}
```

If you want callback functions to carry an argument, just change the `VoidCallBack` to whatever function types.